# Thread vs. Timer vs. etc. to Incremement Variable

Tags: java, android, multithreading, timer

I have seen many posts on using Runnable, TaskTimers, Timers, Threads, etc., but they are all starting to look the same.  So here is a two part question:

1. If I wanted to increment a variable by n once per x seconds, which would I want to use?  (I need the rest of my program to run without skipping a beat!)
2. Why would I use that?

Comment: definately saw the downvote coming, but this question will be very helpful to others like me

Comment: `"Briefly, what are the differences between using a Runnable, TaskTimer, Timer, Thread?"` -- isn't this question a bit broad? Certainly you've done a lot of work reviewing this first and can come up with more specific questions, no?

Comment: ok...for the purposes of incrementing a variable without interupting my program. why is one the best for it?>

Comment: Something you've not even mentioned -- a [ScheduledExecutorService](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/ScheduledExecutorService.html) could work as well. For e.g., look at the [ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor API](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.html). Per its API, `"This class is preferable to Timer when multiple worker threads are needed, or when the additional flexibility or capabilities of ThreadPoolExecutor (which this class extends) are required."`

Comment: Never heard of it, but sounds useful.  I appreciate the lesson on why this is a bad question, but perhaps you could put something in the answer section for me?

Comment: Really any of those would work, except note that the Timer requires a TimerTask. They are not separate solutions. Simplest is probably Timer/TimerTask.

Comment: OK, lemme rephrase the question.  In your expert opinion, which would you suggest for incrementing a variable every second without interupting the rest of my program, and why? :-)

Comment: Timer/TimerTask because it is simple and easy to use and built for this sort of thing. If you want to launch multiple worker threads, then the ThreadPoolExecutor, but this is not what you're trying to do at this time.

Comment: thank you. if u have time, id appreciate a lesson in why the others would also / would not be useful :) if not thanks for your advice

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
ScheduledExecutorService executor = Executors.newScheduledThreadPool(1, new ThreadFactory() {
  public Thread newThread(Runnable r) {
    final Thread result = new Thread(r);
    result.setPriority(Thread.MAX_PRIORITY);
    return result;
  }
});

executor.scheduleAtFixedRate(new TotallyImportantTask(), 0, 10, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
```

A Timer won't work, because you cannot set the actual thread priority, therefore it might or might not run depending on the actual load.

A thread won't work, because you need to call `Thread.sleep(x)` in a loop, and there is no guarantee that it will actually wake up after x seconds. Depending on the OS and situation the times can slightly or greatly vary.

The ScheduledExecutorService actually uses the OS scheduling service (if any) and guarantees that at the correct moment the thread is launched with high priority and therefore all other threads will (if necessary) be put on hold.

Answer (score 0):

Timer with method:
public void schedule(TimerTask task,
            Date firstTime,
            long period)
is probably what your looking for.